# Only specific urls 404 error for dmca complaints

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-404

i have a mp3 website with following urls

i want to redirect only those urls to 404 error page for which i have dmca complaint so in this way i have many urls to be filtered.

how can i do this that only the urls which i want gives 404 error and the else remains the same

for example i want the below url only to show 404 error

http://www.mp3isongs.com/mp3/Talk+Dirty+feat+2+Chainz+.html

and the below will show normally and don't show error message

http://www.mp3isongs.com/mp3/What+I+Might+Do+radio+Edit+.html

Comment: That pretty much depends on how you handle your pages and the programming language you're using. Could you provide more information?

Comment: well the script is in php i think and i want to filter specific urls via .htaccess or by some file in which i can put all those urls which i want to show 404 error...

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error is for pages that do not exist. Why don't you remove the links or put the target="blank" ?